# Query using LEFT JOIN between two large (~16M records) tables runs too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

This is an extension of my first question asked here:
[Group By query running too slow to be functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882518/group-by-query-running-too-slow-to-be-functional/75882702#75882702)

I applied the two column index to the first table and that fixed the slow query issue, but I now need to add more statistics to the query. The first step in this is to join the first table to a couple of others. The inner join has little to no effect on the speed, however the LEFT join slows a ten second query down to 160 seconds. Since I am going to use Explain in this question, I am no longer going to obfuscate the database names so this query will look a little different than the original  question.

Original Query:

```
select
  p.radiologist, 
  concat((sum(p.qa_report_sendback)/count(*))*100, '%') as 'Sent Back'
from patients as p
group by p.radiologist;
```

Runs in about 10 secs.

New Query:

```
select
  p.radiologist, 
  concat((sum(p.qa_report_sendback)/count(*))*100, '%') as 'Sent Back'
from patients as p
INNER JOIN radiologist as rad on p.radiologist = rad.lastname
LEFT JOIN receivable_transactions as rec 
  on p.seq = rec.patient_seq
where rad.company = 1
group by p.radiologist;
```

Runs in about 200 seconds.

The INNER JOIN does not have a noticable effect on the query, however the LEFT JOIN brings it to a screaching halt. There is an index on p.seq, another on rec.patient_seq. The patient table and the receivable transactions tables have both approximately 16M records but it is not a one to one relationship. The explain looks like:

[image]

and the profile looks like:

```
'starting', '0.002945'
'checking permissions', '0.000865'
'checking permissions', '0.000532'
'checking permissions', '0.001156'
'Opening tables', '0.008167'
'init', '0.008097'
'System lock', '0.000573'
'optimizing', '0.005087'
'statistics', '0.007404'
'preparing', '0.000040'
'Creating tmp table', '0.000398'
'Sorting result', '0.000012'
'executing', '0.000005'
'Sending data', '999.999999'
'Creating sort index', '0.020716'
'end', '0.000026'
'query end', '0.003981'
'removing tmp table', '0.003063'
'query end', '0.000014'
'closing tables', '0.013723'
'freeing items', '0.015459'
'cleaning up', '0.017955'
```

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Is that the complete query , you are invoking receivable_transactions as rec but aren't using it in the select

Comment: No, that is not the complete query. I am pulling information out of rec and doing another statistical calculation with it like 'Sent Back' does. However, that calculation takes a case statement and I didn't want to confuse the question by adding another place where the bottleneck could happen. I need the join to work first before I worry about the calculated return value.

Comment: Changing `group by p.radiologist` to  `group by rad.lastname` can potentially speed up your query quite a bit, if you add the composite index `(company, lastname)`.

Comment: @P.Salmon This join may duplicate some rows which effects the output. `rec.patient_seq` obviously is not unique.

Comment: That is correct Akina - patients to rec is a one to many relationship